# English equivalent for the Persian expression "To keep one's face red with slap"

Tags: expressions, idioms, idiom-requests, popular-refrains, phrase-requests

In Persian we have a saying "صورت را با سیلی سرخ نگه داشتن" which literally translates to:

> **To keep one's face red(warm) with slap**

It's used in a situation in which a person, if poor or unfortunate, tries to uphold his/her outward appearance  in a good way in order that others won't notice his/her (financial) issues.

**For example:**
Assume you see your close friend after some time and you realize he is wearing a nice perfume and has put on some flashy clothes. Here is the conversation:

> **Alice**: Wow Bob! You're looking great. Your new job must have paid off!
>
> **Bob**:  Thanks but not really, I'm just **keeping my face red with slap**.

This suggests that although Bob has financial issues, he tries to maintain his appearance so that others wouldn't notice and his honor would be kept.

I tried searching for an English equivalent but nothing came up.
Is there a similar idiom/expression to describe this situation in English?

Comment: ***to keep up appearences*** : to make things look all right whether they are or not. http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/keep+up+appearances

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Put a brave face/front on something** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+a+brave+face+on)

> to behave in a way that makes people think you are happy when you are not
>
> *"They've had some bad luck, but they've put a brave face on their problems."*
> *"She's very ill but she's putting a brave front on it. (= making people believe her illness does not worry her)"*

**Keep up appearances** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/keep+up+appearances)

> to make things look all right whether they are or not.
>
> *"We must keep up appearances even if it means little sacrifices here and there."*
> *"Things may be unpleasant, but we will keep up appearances."*

**Keep (one's) chin up** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/keep+chin+up)

> To be stalwart, courageous, or optimistic in the face of difficulty.
>
> *" Just keep your chin up and tell the judge exactly what happened."*

**Keep one's cool** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/keep+cool)

> to be calm despite danger or difficulty; keep your head
>
> *"Somehow I kept my cool even though Seldon's remarks were unfair and made me angry."*

**Keep your head** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/keep+head)

> to be calm despite danger or difficulty
>
> *" She was very angry. We had to calm her down and encourage her to keep her head."*
> *"Always try to keep your head when others are panicking."*

**Keep one’s head right** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/keep+one%E2%80%99s+head+right)

> *tv.* to maintain control of oneself.
>
> *"Chill, man, chill. You’ve got to keep your head right.*"

**Live in genteel poverty** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/genteel)

> trying to keep the style of a high social class, but with little money
>
> *genteel* — (of people and their way of life) quiet and polite, often in an exaggerated way; from, or pretending to be from, a high social class

Comment: Please let me know if any of these suggestions are bad.

Comment: Thanks @NVZ, those are great suggestions. I particularly liked **Put a brave face/front on something** and **Keep up appearances**. The former was closer to what I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

fake it until you make it; keep up appearances; don't let them see you cry. these are 3 that come to mind.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).